# Feature scaling using python StandardScaler produces negative values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am a newbie in Machine learning. I am trying to use feature scaling on my input training and test data using the python StandardScaler class. However, when I see the scaled values some of them are negative values even though the input values do not have negative values. Is this normal or am I missing anything in my code. Given below the relevant code being used for feature scaling.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
train = sc.fit_transform(train) //train contains training feature matrix
test = sc.transform(test)   //test contains test feature matrix
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

> Standardize features by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance

This means, given an input `x`, transform it to `(x-mean)/std` (where all dimensions and operations are well defined).

So even if your input values are all positive, removing the mean can make some of them negative:

```
>>> x = np.array([3,5,7])
>>> np.mean(x)
5.0
>>> x - np.mean(x)
array([-2.,  0.,  2.])
```

More details:

- http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf (sec. 4.3)
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling
- http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part2/section-16.html